# Django website with sqlite db deployment on heroku

Tags: python, django, sqlite, heroku

I have been reading at many places that Heroku doesn't support sqlite database. Is there no option to use sqlite? Is there any kind of wrapper or plug-in to be used with sqlite so that it can be deployed in Heroku? 
Can anyone share resources or guides to do the same end to end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this. An sqlite database is a file on disk, but the filesystem on Heroku is ephemeral and not shared between dynos, so the db would be lost every time you deploy.

But there is no reason to try. Django already abstracts away all the differences between databases for regular usage. Heroku supports a number of Postgres plans for different use cases, including a free hobby tier.

Comment: So what should I do? Migrate the database to postgres? Or will this be done automatically by heroku?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Your database on Heroku is separate from your local one. Follow the Heroku instructions, including using `dj_database_url` to set the database settings automatically, then the migrations will create your db in Postgres.

Comment: So the way I understand your statement is that, I do not have to make any changes in my application code. I just have to follow the instructions to deploy it on heroku and it will automatically build a postgres database for me. Am I right?