# Django site not updated

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I got my django app configured with AWS S3 and all the media files are hooked up correctly. When I post  a new article, the media files are stored in S3 and everything seems to work fine. After about 5 hours, I checked the site and it was back to a time frame where the article was not posted. This means it went back in time and got regressed to an earlier code? I don't know what is happening, and why after many days of testing it ALWAYS goes back to that one stage. Any advice?

Settings file:

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['XXX.heroku', '127.0.0.1', 'localhost', '.XXX.com, '.XXX']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'django_cleanup',
    'storages',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'analyst.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'analyst.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    "default": {
        "removePlugins": "stylesheetparser",
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'XXX@gmail.com'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'XXX'
EMAIL_PORT = 587


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'XXX'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'XXX'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'XXX'

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'analyst.aws.storage_backends.MediaStorage'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'media'
AWS_S3_REGION = 'ap-southeast-1'
```

Comment: This really looks like something is being rolled back due to a periodic task or configuration and is likely a system administration issue, which needs a lot more information about your configuration.

Comment: @Melvyn I'm a beginner with django, do you want to have a look at my setting.py?

Comment: I don't think it's a Django issue, cause it's very unlikely something gets rolled back on a database level. However, since you're using SQlite, are you overwriting the db.sqlite3 when you (re)deploy?

Comment: Tbh I'm not so sure about that, I haven't really meddled with the DB. However, when I do an update dynamically on the site, it stays for about 5 hours and then resets itself. Didn't have to redeploy or anything for it to be reset

Comment: You can't use SQLite on Heroku. There are [lots of questions about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heroku+sqlite), including [some specifically for Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heroku+sqlite+django). Please remember to search before asking a new question. See [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django website with sqlite db deployment on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51148569/django-website-with-sqlite-db-deployment-on-heroku)

Comment: @Chris Well I came across a similar issue before and I thought letting the S3 handle the media files would take care of it. Now I have to change the DB?

Comment: @Chris please help me understand regarding the issue above. Even if my media, static, css files and all that are stored in the S3, it won't work? I have to change the DB? Like I said I am new to programming so thank you for being patient

Comment: You need to change everything that writes data to the local filesystem. SQLite is just a file sitting there. When you save data to it, you write data to the filesystem. When your dyno restarts, that file gets reset to whatever it contained when your slug was built. Client-server databases don't operate like that: your data will be persisted on a different machine.

Comment: @Chris I see, I get a better picture of it now. So right now the solution is to look into postgres? If so, could you suggest a link I could follow to make the changes necessery?