# Why are some of my photos missing after I re-deploy heroku even though I have s3 set up

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3

So when I go to re-deploy my heroku, some of my profiles are missing photos, and the same ones every single time. When I upload a user photo, I can see a copy of it being put into my AWS bucket. And it uploads and shows up. But when I re-deploy, it's gone. Why is this happening?

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)



MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')


#Settings for django-bootstrap3
BOOTSTRAP4 = {
    'include_jquery' : True,
}



#S3 BUCKETS CONFIG



AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATIC_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Comment: "But when I re-deploy, it's gone"—what is gone? The photo no longer exists in your bucket?

Comment: @Chris the photo is still there in my bucket on AWS, but it's gone from my profile of which I uploaded it too. The link to that photo is there, but the photo itself is gone.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your database settings (make sure to take out any sensitive information like passwords).

Comment: @Chris What do you mean by database settings?

Comment: I mean your [database settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases). Are you using SQLite?

Comment: yes I am using that

Comment: @Chris Ok just added it

Comment: That's your problem. You can't use SQLite on Heroku. This is well-documented and covered extensively on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django website with sqlite db deployment on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51148569/django-website-with-sqlite-db-deployment-on-heroku)

Comment: @Chris Wait, I thought I was using s3 as the location to hold my data? So why would sql lite be effecting my photo images if they are being stored on s3? I'm still new to all this, so forgive me if I'm a noob.

Comment: @Chris It sort of answers my question, the article. However, I am still confused as to why my local database is effecting what's stored on s3. I already have s3 AWS set up, and I can see every time a user uploads a photo, a new one is created in my s3 bucket. So why is it that once I re-deploy, that photo from my s3 bucket disappears? When I originally created my s3 bucket, I uploaded photos to my heroku and they are all still there even after re-deploying. It's just that when I try to add a new photo , it doesn't work. I  maybe I messed something up. But are you saying it's cuz of sql lite?

Comment: Your database holds most of your data. For files (including images), it normally holds a path to the image but not the image itself. Storing your images on S3 is necessary because of Heroku's [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem)—any changes you make to it will be lost frequently. But your SQLite database is _also_ a file. Which means _it_ is also incompatible with Heroku's filesystem. Your S3 files are staying put, but your database records (including the path the any files) are being lost. A client-server database like Postgres solves this.

Comment: @Chris Got it. That I can understand better. What if I simply took out my Sqlite from my version control?

Comment: That still won't work. Anything you change on Heroku's filesystem can be lost at any moment.